# Skipping First Password Prompt when Dual Booting Ubuntu and Windows 10 with Encryption

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, encryption

I currently have both Ubuntu and Windows 10 installed on a system, successfully dual booting.

Windows uses bitlocker on the system drive and Ubuntu uses LVM on LUKS.

GRUB2 is used to boot the system, which works fine, with one caveat:

The system prompts for the Ubuntu decryption password prior to GRUB2 loading its menu, then a second time for the respective password for each OS. The message at the first password prompt is:

```
Attempting to decrypt master key...
Enter Passphrase for hd1,gpt4 (*Number/letter string*)
```

This is despite both operating systems sharing the same EFI partition that is unencrypted, so GRUB shouldn't need the password to load that menu, only to boot the linux distro, right...?

I am suspicious that perhaps GRUB2 has ended up on the encrypted Linux section of the drive, but I don't know how to verify that (advice welcome).

---

Notes on GRUB2 Installation

Due to an error in the installation process I had to manually install GRUB2 from a live USB after the rest of the installation process finished, using these steps:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda* /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount /dev/sda+ /mnt/boot/efi
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda+ /mnt/boot/efi
mkdir /mnt/hostrun
mount --bind /run /mnt/hostrun
chroot /mnt
mkdir /run/lvm
mount --bind /hostrun/lvm /run/lvm
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt/boot/efi
umount /mnt/hostrun
umount /mnt/run/lvm
umount /mnt
```

In an effort to solve this myself I also tried

```
grub-install --force /dev/sda1
```

but the problem still exists, with the question being:

*How can I remove that first password prompt, so only the respective OS password is required at boot?*

Comment: That's alot of encryption, data must be priceless. You said it yourself in the post when you had install trouble and had to input grub files. I bet there's your issue - figure out the first problem first

Comment: Do you have a /boot partition for Ubuntu that is not encrypted with LUKS? Note that I'm not referring to your EFI partition which gets mounted at /boot/efi.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in my response, I have created a new question with (hopefully) clearer information should you wish to take a look. Thanks for your thoughts here :)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106136/prompted-for-luks-password-twice-on-boot-despite-separate-unencrypted-boot-part